# Prolog non-homogenous lists

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to write non-homogenous lists in prolog?
I want to create a list which contains symbols and integers. Something like:
**`[A 2 3 B C D E]`**

Thanks

P.S. I user Turbo Prolog 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turbo Prolog requires that list elements be of a single type. *But* there is a way around this - you just need to define a single type which can represent both integers and symbols. You can do this by defining a *compound domain*, in which each different type is wrapped with a different functor. So, for example:

```
mixed_type = i(integer); s(symbol).
mixed_list = mixed_type*.
```

The downside is that you need a functor around every list element, which is a bit awkward:

```
[s(a), i(2), i(3), s(b), s(c)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Prolog only has one data type, so *every* list is homogenous.

Every element in Prolog is just a **term**. `a` is a term, `a(x,y)` is a term, `3` is a term, and there's nothing in the language which makes a distinction between them. Of course, plenty of built-in predicates discriminate based on type - you can't expect an answer from `X is 1 + a` - but there's no distinction in the language itself.

So to answer your question, you can put absolutely whatever you want in your list, including all of the above - the following is valid Prolog:

```
L = [a, a(x,y), 3, X is 1 + a].
```

Comment: @CapelliC There are certainly plenty of built-in predicates which have a notion of type, but they're part of the library, not really part of the language. Probably the only things I'd count as "operations" in pure Prolog are rule lookups and term unification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no types in Prolog. You must write uppercase letters with quotes : 
['A', 2, 3, 'B', 'C' 'D', 'E', f, g]

Comment: Ok ok, but how do I define it as a domain? Because when I try to mix symbols with integers, it gives me: "Type error: Wrong object type"

Comment: @AdiUlici Can you give a bit of context? Sounds like it's the thing reading the list that's complaining about the types, not Prolog itself.

Comment: Well, if I want to create a list of integers, I create a domain `list = integer*`, but what do I write if I want to create a list with integers and symbols? I forgot to mention, I use an older prolog: Turbo Prolog 2.0